# How to include CSS file and scripts file in Partial view MVC using Fetch API

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net-mvc, progressive-web-apps, fetch-api

I am working on to add service worker in my Asp.net MVC Web Application. CSS files and JS files are included using @Style.Render and @Scripts.Render in _Layout.cshtml. How I can include these files using fetch API. I would like to cache my js files and CSS files with the help of to filter out fetch request. I try that below code. it returns that success message. but the file is not included. Any suggestion?

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    fetch('/Content/Site.css')
        .then(function (response) {
            console.log('script loaded successfully');
        })
        .catch(function (ex) {
            console.log('failed', ex);
        });
</script>
```

Comment: Scripts should not be in partial views - only in the main view of its layout.

Comment: I include above code in the main view. but still, it is not working.

Answer (score 0):

I don't have an exact answer, but more of a suggestion.

MVC partial views are conceptually similar to having an app shell (think master page), possibly a layout and then page content, which could then have child components (like a partial view).

Now, MVC renders on the client, so the rendered page gets sent down the wire and there should be nothing needed to compose the page in the service worker....

However, for some applications I render pages in the service worker. I published an example if this technique this past Spring for the Philly Code Camp schedule PWA I made, https://love2dev.com/blog/phillycc-service-worker/.

Basically I pre-cache the appshell, layout and other core markup components. In this example I fetch the JSON by intercepting the request for the HTML. If I have the HTML response cached I return it, if not I fetch the JSON. When the JSON responds I use it to render (I use mustache) the markup with the page's shell, layout, etc. Ultimately I render the markup and cache it as the response.

I could also return the appShell, appShell + Layout, etc (as needed) and then render in the client thread, which is sort of like a SPA, just without the gnarly hashchange handling. It's pretty easy to do that too, target.innerHTML = template.render(…).